# how to pass get variables via request specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'd like to pass a named variable in my rspec call to match

this is the route:

```
match '/api/get-pairings/:global_id' => 'api#get_pairings', :as => :get_pairings
```

this is what I have but doesn't work:

```
it "should get pairings for a specific id" do
   {:get => get_pairings_path, :global_id => 1000  }.should route_to(:controller => "api", :action => "get_pairings")
   {:get => get_pairings_path, :params => { :global_id => 1000 } }.should route_to(:controller => "api", :action => "get_pairings")
end
```

Any ideas?

thx in advance

Comment: How about `:get => get_pairings_path(:global_id => 1000)`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the variable to the `_path` method for the specs to work:

```
it "should get pairings for a specific id" do
  {:get => get_pairings_path(:global_id => 1000) }.
    should route_to(:controller => "api",
                    :action => "get_pairings",
                    :global_id => "1000")
end
```